# QuickSort sorting positive ints, sometimes first value is negative int after ordering

Tags: c, quicksort

I am implementing a QuickSort in C which pivot is variable (can be middle, median, or aleatory). It is selected inside an `switch` clause.

My implementation is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// swap two values
void intercambio(int *arrayDatos, int inicio, int fin) {
    int temporal;

    temporal = arrayDatos[inicio];
    arrayDatos[inicio] = arrayDatos[fin];
    arrayDatos[fin] = temporal;
}

// calculate median
int calcularMediana(int a[], int left, int right) { //Uses median of three partitioning technique
    int center = (left + right) / 2;
    if (a[center] < a[left])
        intercambio(a, left, center);
    if (a[right] < a[left])
        intercambio(a, left, right);
    if (a[right] < a[center])
        intercambio(a, center, right);

    intercambio(a, center, right - 1); //since the largest is already in the right.
    return right - 1;
}

// arrayDatos is array to sorting
// inicio is start of the partition
// fin is end of the partition
// variante is the variable which select the pivote type (0, 1 or 2)
int quickSort(int *arrayDatos, int inicio, int fin, int variante) {
    int pivote, i, j;

    // vector size 1 -> dont do nothing
    if (inicio >= fin)
        return 0;
    // vector size 1 -> check if is necessary swap it
    if (inicio + 1 == fin) {
        if (arrayDatos[inicio] > arrayDatos[fin]) { // No están ordenados los dos números, intercambiar
            intercambio(arrayDatos, inicio, fin);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    // vector size 3+ 
    switch (variante) {
        case 0: // MIDDLE
        {
            int medio = (inicio + fin) / 2;
            // swap pivot and last element
            intercambio(arrayDatos, medio, fin);
            break;
        }
        case 1: //ALEATORY
        {
            int aleatorio = inicio + rand() % (fin - inicio);
            // swap pivot and last element
            intercambio(arrayDatos, aleatorio, fin);
            break;
        }
        case 2: //MEDIAN
        {
            int mediana = calcularMediana(arrayDatos, inicio, fin);
            // swap pivot and last element
            intercambio(arrayDatos, mediana, fin);
            break;
        }
        default:
            printf("No valid pivot. \n");
            break;
    }
    pivote = arrayDatos[fin];
    // start partition
    for (i = inicio, j = fin - 1;;) {
        while ((i <= fin - 1) && (arrayDatos[i] <= pivote)) {
            i++;
        }
        while ((j >= inicio) && (pivote <= arrayDatos[j])) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i < j) { // swap numbers
            intercambio(arrayDatos, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        } else // end partition
            break;
    }
    // restore pivot
    intercambio(arrayDatos, i, fin);
    // end partition, recursive calls
    quickSort(arrayDatos, inicio, i - 1, variante); // Vector de la izquierda del pivote
    quickSort(arrayDatos, i + 1, fin, variante); // Vector de la derecha del pivote

    return (0);
}

int main() {
    int *a = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    a[0] = 2;
    a[1] = 5;
    a[2] = 4;
    a[3] = 9;

    quickSort(a, 0, 4, 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
        printf("%i \n", a[i]);
}
```

But sometimes I get an negative number as first element after sorting, other times sorting is well done.

I mean (assuming vector: `{5, 1, 4}`), possible results are:

- sometimes result is ok: `{1, 4, 5}`
- sometimes result is not ok: `{-124565646, 4, 5}`

I have looked for a possible mistake inside the code, but I have not found any.

Any idea why could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a confusion in your code as to whether the element at `fin` is included in the array to be sorted or excluded.

The function `quickSort` seems to include it but you call `quickSort(a, 0, 4, 2);` from `main` with an array of size `4` and the value `4` for `fin`, hence including the element at index `4`, which is not part of the array.

As a consequence, the code has undefined behavior and the output can be unpredictable. Accessing an element beyond the end of the array may cause a fatal error, or may return a meaningless value which is what you observe. If this value happens to be negative, `quickSort` will move it to the beginning of the array and the output will show it.

With the current implementation, the call in `main` should be `quickSort(a, 0, 3, 2);`.

Yet it would be more consistent in C for `fin` to be the index of the first value excluded from the range. This requires more changes in the code.

Note also that there is potential arithmetic overflow in `int medio = (inicio + fin) / 2;`. You should instead write:

```
    int medio = inicio + (fin - inicio) / 2;
```

Here is a modified version of your code with a validation step and some statistics on the number of comparisons and exchanges:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static long long comparisons, exchanges;

// swap two values
void intercambio(int *arrayDatos, int i, int j) {
    int temporal = arrayDatos[i];
    arrayDatos[i] = arrayDatos[j];
    arrayDatos[j] = temporal;
    exchanges++;
}

// calculate median of 3
int calcularMediana(int a[], int left, int right) {
    int center = left + (right - left) / 2;
    comparisons++;
    if (a[center] < a[left])
        intercambio(a, left, center);
    comparisons++;
    if (a[right] < a[left])
        intercambio(a, left, right);
    comparisons++;
    if (a[right] < a[center])
        intercambio(a, center, right);
    return center;
}

// arrayDatos is array to sorting
// inicio is start of the partition (included)
// end is end of the partition (excluded)
// variante is the variable which select the pivot selection mode (0, 1 or 2)
void quickSort(int *arrayDatos, int inicio, int end, int variante) {
    int pivote, i, j, fin = end - 1;

    // vector size less than 2 -> dont do nothing
    if (end - inicio < 2)
        return;

    // vector size 2 -> check if is necessary swap it
    if (end - inicio == 2) {
        comparisons++;
        if (arrayDatos[inicio] > arrayDatos[fin]) {
            // No están ordenados los dos números, intercambiar
            intercambio(arrayDatos, inicio, fin);
        }
        return;
    }
    // vector size 3+
    switch (variante) {
    case 0: // Middle
        {
            int medio = inicio + (end - inicio) / 2;
            // swap pivot and last element
            intercambio(arrayDatos, medio, fin);
            break;
        }
    case 1: //Aleatory
        {
            int aleatorio = inicio + rand() % (end - inicio);
            // swap pivot and last element
            intercambio(arrayDatos, aleatorio, fin);
            break;
        }
    case 2: //Median of 3
        {
            int mediana = calcularMediana(arrayDatos, inicio, fin);
            // swap pivot and last element
            intercambio(arrayDatos, mediana, fin);
            break;
        }
    default:
        printf("Invalid pivot selection method %d.\n", variante);
        return;
    }
    pivote = arrayDatos[fin];
    // start partition
    for (i = inicio, j = fin - 1;;) {
        while ((i <= fin - 1) && ((void)comparisons++, arrayDatos[i] <= pivote)) {
            i++;
        }
        while ((j >= inicio) && ((void)comparisons++, pivote <= arrayDatos[j])) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i < j) { // swap numbers
            intercambio(arrayDatos, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        } else { // end partition
            break;
        }
    }
    // restore pivot
    intercambio(arrayDatos, i, fin);
    // end partition, recursive calls
    quickSort(arrayDatos, inicio, i, variante); // Vector de la izquierda del pivote
    quickSort(arrayDatos, i + 1, end, variante); // Vector de la derecha del pivote
}

/* up to 3 arguments can be passed to this program:
   - the array size
   - the pivot selection method
   - the maximum element value
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = argc < 2 ? 100 : (int)strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    int method = argc < 3 ? 2 : (int)strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0);
    int max = argc < 4 ? n - 1 : (int)strtol(argv[3], NULL, 0);
    int *a = malloc(n * sizeof(*a));

    if (a == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory for %d elements\n", n);
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % (max + 1);
    }

    printf("n=%d, m=%d, method=%d -> ", n, max, method);
    fflush(stdout);

    comparisons = exchanges = 0;
    quickSort(a, 0, n, method);

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i - 1] > a[i]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ordering error: a[%d] = %d > a[%d] = %d\n",
                    i - 1, a[i - 1], i, a[i]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%lld comparisons, %lld exchanges\n", comparisons, exchanges);
    return 0;
}
```

Here are some runtime output showing how the algorithm behaves nicely for random data, exhibiting the expected average time complexity of **N log(N)**, but quickly degrades to **N<sup>2</sup>** for data with lots of duplicates and ultimately crashes for large uniform datasets because of **stack overflow**.

```
n=100000, m=99999, method=2 -> 1976491 comparisons, 469625 exchanges
n=100000, m=99999, method=1 -> 2047869 comparisons, 431256 exchanges
n=100000, m=99999, method=0 -> 2186895 comparisons, 424248 exchanges
n=100000, m=10, method=0 -> 436941482 comparisons, 228596 exchanges
n=100000, m=10, method=1 -> 393712217 comparisons, 226964 exchanges
n=100000, m=10, method=2 -> 385925150 comparisons, 234864 exchanges
n=100000, m=1, method=2 -> 3347387811 comparisons, 175168 exchanges
n=100000, m=0, method=2 -> Segmentation fault: 11
```

Here are some hints to improve your implementation:

- only recurse on the smaller subrange and iterate on the larger one ;
- use the Bentley McIlroy approach to isolate duplicates of the pivot value ;
- limit the recursion to a few dozen levels and switch to heap sort for pathological sets, that can be constructed with anti-qsort.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much @chqrlie, It is so helpful. Thank you, again :)